# Blender causes my screen backlights to flicker

Tags: display, backlight, blender

I am using a desktop with a Radeon HD 5xxx CGU.

Every time I work with Blender (no matter the version), my screen flickers at what seems to be random times (meaning I don't feel I am doing anything special when it happens). The backlight brightness gets weaker, then back to normal.

I've seen it happen a couple of times before, though I didn't really pay attention thinking this was a problem with the power or whatever, but with Blender it is quite constant.

Comment: This happens when my laptop is running some intensive 3d software like blender on battery

Comment: What is a CGU ? Is it a CPU ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please give me more details?

It may be a driver problem that you can solve the following way:

`sudo apt-get install fglrx`

If you have already AMD propietary drivers uninstall them first or:

`sudo apt-get upgrade fglrx`

Hope this information solved the problem.

Comment: This is the driver I am using : OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on AMD CEDAR
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 10.1.0-devel
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30